# Need to get all values of a particular key of JSON in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am getting the following `json` data from `pycurl` in python. All I need to get those values into a list in python.

```
OUTPUT:
[{ 'name' : 'aaa', 'contact' : '123' },{ 'name' : 'bbb', 'contact' : '345' },{ 'name' : 'ccc', 'contact' : '555' }]
```

I need to get all those values of `name` key into a python list.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? (hint: it's __really__ trivial)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a valid json data. Single quotes aren't allowed in JSON files. If that is the case, you need to first fix the JSON string.

```
import json

json_data_string = "[{ 'name' : 'aaa', 'contact' : '123' },{ 'name' : 'bbb', 'contact' : '345' },{ 'name' : 'ccc', 'contact' : '555' }]"
json_data_string = json_data_string.replace("'", "\"") #provided JSON content doesn't contains single quotes as part of values.

data = json.loads(json_data_string)
names = map(lambda datum: datum['name'], data)
```

Comment: Yeah, but the web api I am using is returning the data in that way.

Comment: Yes, that is why I was looking the way.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers It is not a valid json, for different reasons than I predicted however.

Comment: @LinuxAutomations I have changed my answer.

Comment: @hspandher indeed- I had not spotted the single quotes issue.

Comment: @hspandher , According to this URL it is a proper JSON DATA SET [link](https://adobe.github.io/Spry/samples/data_region/JSONDataSetSample.html)

Comment: @hspandher no need for escapes, single quotes are legal in Python : `json_data_string.replace("'", '"')`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Just to be consistent with the first parameter, I did so. :)

Comment: @LinuxAutomations the problem is with the single quotes, not with the object being an array.

Comment: @hspandher , This what I was looking for. `map(lambda datum: datum['name'], data)` . I was using a loop and this can be a best option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

jobtittles =  list(map(lambda datum: datum['jobtitle'], jsonVal))

I used the above code in order to do something simila, jsonVal = JSON as string
and ['jobtitle'] is the key in the JSON string, jobtitles is an array.

It worked wrapping the map() function with a list() function.